# Spring 5 - No me genera el autonúmerico, debo marcar el id desde la BD como autonúmerico

Tags: java, spring

```
package com.udemy.entity;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
@Table(name = "log")
public class Log {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "date")
private Date date;

@Column(name = "details")
private String details;

@Column(name = "username")
private String username;

@Column(name = "url")
private String url;

public Log(Date date, String details, String username, String url) {
    super();
    this.date = date;
    this.details = details;
     this.username = username;
      this.url = url;
   }

public Log() {

}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getDetails() {
    return details;
}

public void setDetails(String details) {
    this.details = details;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

---

### Solución

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private int id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Para generar el auto numérico debes de agregar estas etiquetas:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
```

Para trabajar con tus identitys te recomiendo activar dentro de `application.properties` la siguiente linea:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

> **¡¡CUIDADO!!** Esto hace un drop a toda la BD cada vez que se reinicia el servidor.

Con spring no es necesario hacer modificaciones a la BD de datos a menos que sean cosas muy especificas o que tengas un ambiente de producción.